# Cannot login remotely to Database engine via Meraki VPN

Tags: networking, ssms

I have been facing a issue while connecting database via Meraki VPN when working remotely.
When working from office it does not ask me to login using Azure account. Because we do not have one. However, it keeps asking to login and then when I do so it says your account does not have valid subscriptions while there is no need of that.

I have done all troubleshooting steps mentioned on Microsoft reference doc, turned of firewall [Follow the ink to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdgFW.png). Added inbound rule and whatnot.

Is there any other way to deal with this problem. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I *suspect* that when you are working at the office your office's IP is in the remote hosts firewall, and so permitted to connect. The prompt is asking you to sign into Azure so you can add your IP address to the firewall rules; I doubt you have that type of access. You need to speak to your Network Administrator, as I *assume* your VPN has not been set up correctly to direct connections to your Azure SQL instance via your workplaces network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for this by working with our IT department. My IP address was not whitelisted by my company. After whitelisting, I could login in SSMS vis VPN.

Tip:- Before trying to troubleshoot by following steps given by Microsoft, make sure your personal device is registered as well with your IT department.